# How do I change the background color of the folded block in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

After folding a block, it is marked with a different background color.
How to make this color equal to the basic color of the editor's background?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wImp.png)

Answer (score 14):

You have two options.  If you want to tweak the colors used for the folded area background, use this in your settings:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "editor.foldBackground": "#ff000000"
}
```

Rather than trying to match your editor background you could just make it transparent as I did above.  The last two digits of the hex color are for opacity.

See in general https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

---

Easier is to just disable folding highlighting in the regular settings:

> Editor > Folding Highlight

Comment: I'm confirming this works for me, for folded blocks of code. I, however, am actually looking for another color I cannot find documented anywhere. I want the little red arrow in the gutter that has uncommitted changes collapsed in it to not be red. I'm going to ask a question in SO now.